# Train neural network to determine color image quality

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I'm looking for someone who know if it is possible to train a neural network to tell if the image provided live up to the trained expectation.

Let's say we have a neural network which trained to read a 800x800 pixel color image. Therefore, I will have 1,920,000 input and many hidden layers and a single output. I am planning to prepare 2000 photos which consists of 1000 bad photos (blurry, too dark, too bright, etc...) and 1000 good photos and train the neural network to identify if this photo is considered as "good". Which if it is good, then the output will be True (or anything > 0.5), anything that's bad will output False (or anything <= 0.5).

I don't need the neural network to give reasoning, I just need to detect any bad photos based on the training. So when the neural network is giving photo 2001 (which is a new photo), it will use its trained network to determine if it is good or bad photo.

Is this a good use of neural network?

Looking forward to positive discussion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good application of convolutional neural networks. There are a number of libraries and services available for doing this.

[Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) is a tool for doing this, though I don't have any experience with it. Do some googling for other tools, search for "convolutional neural networks".

For services there's [Clarifai](http://www.clarifai.com/), [MetaMind](https://www.metamind.io/vision/train), and [Project Oxford](https://www.projectoxford.ai/vision) to name a few. They probably aren't free though.